# How to add "text/javascript" to <head> in Nuxt

Tags: nuxt.js

I have the following script I have to add in the `<head>` tag. But in Nuxt I have to add it as an objext in nuxt.config.js.

How do I do this?

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  /* To enable Participant Auto Authentication, uncomment this code below (https://docs.growsurf.com/getting-started/participant-auto-authentication) */
  /*
  window.grsfConfig = {
    email: "participant@email.com",// Replace this with the participant's email address
    hash: "HASH_VALUE" // Replace this with the SHA-256 HMAC value
  };
  */
  (function(g,r,s,f){g.grsfSettings={campaignId:"mpw47p",version:"2.0.0"};s=r.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];f=r.createElement("script");f.async=1;f.src="https://app.growsurf.com/growsurf.js"+"?v="+g.grsfSettings.version;f.setAttribute("grsf-campaign", g.grsfSettings.campaignId);!g.grsfInit?s.appendChild(f):"";})(window,document);
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

2 approachs for this

1. first: use nuxt `head()` in nuxt-page-component (**recommended**)

```js
export default{
    head(){
        return {
            script: [
                {
                    type:'text/javascript',
                    innerHTML: `/* To enable Participant Auto Authentication, uncomment this code below (https://docs.growsurf.com/getting-started/participant-auto-authentication) */
  /*
  window.grsfConfig = {
    email: "participant@email.com",// Replace this with the participant's email address
    hash: "HASH_VALUE" // Replace this with the SHA-256 HMAC value
  };
  */
  (function(g,r,s,f){g.grsfSettings={campaignId:"mpw47p",version:"2.0.0"};s=r.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];f=r.createElement("script");f.async=1;f.src="https://app.growsurf.com/growsurf.js"+"?v="+g.grsfSettings.version;f.setAttribute("grsf-campaign", g.grsfSettings.campaignId);!g.grsfInit?s.appendChild(f):"";})(window,document);`
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

in `nuxt.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
    head: {
        script: [
            {
                type:'text/javascript',
                innerHTML: `/* To enable Participant Auto Authentication, uncomment this code below (https://docs.growsurf.com/getting-started/participant-auto-authentication) */
  /*
  window.grsfConfig = {
    email: "participant@email.com",// Replace this with the participant's email address
    hash: "HASH_VALUE" // Replace this with the SHA-256 HMAC value
  };
  */
  (function(g,r,s,f){g.grsfSettings={campaignId:"mpw47p",version:"2.0.0"};s=r.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];f=r.createElement("script");f.async=1;f.src="https://app.growsurf.com/growsurf.js"+"?v="+g.grsfSettings.version;f.setAttribute("grsf-campaign", g.grsfSettings.campaignId);!g.grsfInit?s.appendChild(f):"";})(window,document);`
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

here is what you get
[image]

2. second: custom `index.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html {{ HTML_ATTRS }}>
  <head {{ HEAD_ATTRS }}>
    {{ HEAD }}
<script type="text/javascript">
  /* To enable Participant Auto Authentication, uncomment this code below (https://docs.growsurf.com/getting-started/participant-auto-authentication) */
  /*
  window.grsfConfig = {
    email: "participant@email.com",// Replace this with the participant's email address
    hash: "HASH_VALUE" // Replace this with the SHA-256 HMAC value
  };
  */
  (function(g,r,s,f){g.grsfSettings={campaignId:"mpw47p",version:"2.0.0"};s=r.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];f=r.createElement("script");f.async=1;f.src="https://app.growsurf.com/growsurf.js"+"?v="+g.grsfSettings.version;f.setAttribute("grsf-campaign", g.grsfSettings.campaignId);!g.grsfInit?s.appendChild(f):"";})(window,document);
</script>
  </head>
  <body {{ BODY_ATTRS }}>
    {{ APP }}
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried your solution with head(), but I'm getting unescaped quotation marks in the rendered HTML

Answer (score 1):

The right way in Nuxt is to create your own plugin for GrowSurf (see [nuxt plugin docs](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/plugins)).

First, create your plugin in a new file `plugins/growsurf.js`:

```js
/* eslint-disable */

export default ({ app }) => {
  /*
   ** Only run on client-side and only in production mode
   */
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    return;
  }

  /* To enable Participant Auto Authentication, uncomment this code below (https://docs.growsurf.com/getting-started/participant-auto-authentication) */
  /*
  window.grsfConfig = {
    email: "participant@email.com",// Replace this with the participant's email address
    hash: "HASH_VALUE" // Replace this with the SHA-256 HMAC value
  };
  */
  (function(g,r,s,f){g.grsfSettings={campaignId:"mpw47p",version:"2.0.0"};s=r.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];f=r.createElement("script");f.async=1;f.src="https://app.growsurf.com/growsurf.js"+"?v="+g.grsfSettings.version;f.setAttribute("grsf-campaign", g.grsfSettings.campaignId);!g.grsfInit?s.appendChild(f):"";})(window,document);

}
```

Then tell Nuxt to import it in your main application:

```js
// nuxt.config.js

export default {
  plugins: [{ src: '~plugins/growsurf.js', mode: 'client' }]
}
```

In addition, you can find a similar example for Google Analytics in the official Nuxt FAQ: https://nuxtjs.org/faq/ga